# Code works in CSHTML but does not work in external Javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, web, post

I'm trying to move my script from CSHTML to an external Javascript file. All the scripts runs perfectly except from one function: `$.post('@Url.Action("GetPoint", "Main")').done(function (xml)`

The error I get on the browser debugger is:

> jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:58153/@Url.Action(%22GetPoint%22,%20%22Main%22) 404 (Not Found)

How can I make this function work??

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js";
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

var createPoint = function(ctx, lat, lon) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(lat, lon, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}
var isFirstMission = document.getElementById("first").value;
var ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

if (isFirstMission) {
  // ...
} else {
  myTimer = (function(ctx) {

    $.post('@Url.Action("GetPoint", "Main")').done(function(xml) { // This function does not work..
      alert(xml);
      var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
      $xml = $(xmlDoc);
      var lat = (parseFloat($xml.find("lat").text()) + 90)(screen.height / 180);
      var lon = (parseFloat($xml.find("lon").text()) + 180) * (screen.height / 360);
      alert(lat);
      alert(lon);

      createPoint(ctx, lat, lon);
    });
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    myTimer(ctx);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: It won't work in an external JS file because you're using Razor syntax: `$.post('@Url.Action("GetPoint", "Main")')`. That's only interpreted in CSHTML files

Comment: Also, as an aside, you should really be using a boolean for `isFirstMission`, not a string.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've got to say, it is fascinating `if ("true" === isFirstMission) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server-side C# (Razor) code isn't interpreted in `.js` files.  (Nor should it be, you don't want to go down that road.)

Instead, something you can do is just set JavaScript variables in your Razor-driven code (possibly global, depending on how you manage scope in your JavaScript code) and use those values in your external JavaScript.  So perhaps something like this in the Razor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var getPointURL = '@Url.Action("GetPoint", "Main")';
</script>
```

And elsewhere you can use that value:

```
$.post(getPointURL)
```

There are a variety of ways to manage/scale/etc. this approach, depending on your growing needs in your system.  But in general the idea is that anything which is dynamic from server-side code is in the Razor file and then the page's JavaScript would use it later.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Javascript file is not parsed as C# on the server, so the `'@Url.Action("GetPoint", "Main")'` string is taken literally.  To solve this you can set a variable in the cshtml file, so that it is parsed, and use that variable in the Javascript file.

In the cshtml file...

```
<script>
    var postUrl = '@Url.Action("GetPoint", "Main")';
</script>
```

Then include your Javascript file *below* that declaration, and change the post to this...

```
$.post(postUrl).done(// etc..
```